# GTM - Get undefined value for Click URL variables

Tags: google-tag-manager

My click url looks like

```
<a href="https://myurl.com/api/public/exports/56555?productCodes=356.585.666&culture=en-US">Download</a>
```

I always get undefined for the two variables productCodes and culture in GTM.

**Setup in GTM:**

I added two user-defined variables in GTM - productCodes and culture. Example variable culture:
[image]

After that, I created a trigger "Click - Just Links" and finally a tag:
[image]

And here is what I get in the preview:
[image]

I would like to get the 356.585.666 as productCodes and en-US as culture. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Google Tag Manager uses URL of the current page as the source of the URL value.

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7683362

You should choose built-in variable `Click URL` as a URL Source in your custom variable:

[image]

Comment: **Thanks zborovskaya**. So easy! :-)